# Como compartilhar um sistema por uma rede interna

Tags: php, easyphp

Tenho um sistema funcionando no EasyPHP da minha máquina e gostaria que todos os computadores que estão na mesma rede que eu pudessem acessar através do link:

```
http://MinhaMáquina/PastaDoSistema
```

Já existe um sistema feito por outra pessoa nessa máquina e que é acessado pelos outros computadores da rede dessa maneira.

Eu já tentei compartilhar a pasta e tal, mas por não entender nada de infraestrutura todos os sistemas que eu desenvolvi ainda não estão disponíveis.

Alguém conhece alguma maneira de compartilhar esses sistemas?

Comment: Olá Mariana, qual erro ocorre? Seria o erro 403?

Comment: Seria bom [edit] e por mais detalhes do que tentou (e descrever as dificuldades) - Tem vários problemas envolvidos nesse setup, a começar pelo seu serviço estar rodando no IP de rede e não no localhost (são coisas BEM diferentes). Depois disso tem que ver a porta onde o sistema roda (ou se existem hosts virtuais, já que é mais de uma aplicação na mesma máquina). Em seguida, vem a questão do DNS, para os outros equipamentos localizarem o endereço (mesmo que interno).

Comment: Então, no meu computador funciona, mas quando eu envio o link para outros usuários dá erro 404 Página não encontrada.

Comment: Peço que retirem a classificação de duplicata da minha pergunta uma vez que a resposta não resolve o meu problema.